# How do I pass data to clients in a circular array? Node.js socket.io

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am using socket.io and node.js for my little multiplayer game. I have an array of users.

```
index.html 

socket.emit('1st word',$wordInput.val());



server.js
users = [];
//rest of code

socket.on('1st word', function(data){
//here is where i was thinking of doing a circular array

});
```

What I want to do is make a circular array. So lets say there are 3 users. user 1 sends to user 2, user 2 sends to user 3 and user 3 sends to user 1. I want it to send like that for 3 turns(because the length of users is 3).

any advice would really help! Pls ask q's for more clarification if you have any! THANKS

Comment: When you say "array", do you mean "chain of communication"? As compared to an array data structure? Why wouldn't you have each user get its update directly from the server? That way if an individual user drops out your chain isn't broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can do it like this :

```
//lets say all the user have different id
//index.html user 1
var user1="abcde1"
//you add user id into the server first using socket.io lets say you emit adduser to server 
socket.emit("adduser",{user:user1})
//this will emit back if there is another user
socket.on("emitback",function(data){
socket.emit("adduser",{user:data.user})
})
```

then in the server side

```
//server.js
var user=[]
socket.on("adduser",function(data){
if(user.indexOf(data.user)==-1){
 //we add user into array user
 user.push(data.user)
}
//if the array already has the id of the user we emit to user 2
else if(user.indexOf(data.user)>-1){
//if user array length is longer than 1 we emit to next user if not we emit to ourselves
if(user.length>1 && user.indexOf(data.user)!=user.length-1){
socket.emit("emitback",{user:user[user.indexOf(data.user)+1]})
}
//this will emit to the first user because this is the last user
else if(user.length>1 && user.indexOf(data.user)==user.length-1){
socket.emit("emitback",{user:user[0]})
}
else if(user.length==1){
socket.emit("emitback",{user:user[user.indexOf(data.user)]})
}
}
})
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for thank you! The only edit I would suggest is notice how in every if clause you do socket.emit()...I want to emit only to that user. So I did users[0].emit...users[1].emit...and so on. But this template helped me do that.

Answer (score 0):

Socket does not send from user to user, Each user connects to the server and sends their commands to the server.

you will have to keep track of your users, and send commands between each other on the server side.

```
/// Server.js
var users = []

io.sockets.on('connect', (socket) => {

  socket.on("joingame", (jgCallback) => {
    if (users.length < 3) {
      if (users.length > 0) {
        users[users.length - 1].nextSocket = socket; // connect this socket to the previous one
      }
      users.push(socket);
      if (users.length === 3) {
        socket.nextSocket = users[0]; // connect this socket to the first one
      }
      jgCallback({ success: true })
    }
    else {
      jgCallback({ success: false })
    }
  })
  socket.on("sendword", (payload, swCallback) => {
    if (users.length === 3 && socket.nextSocket) { // There are 3 users, and This socket has a "nextSocket" property
      socket.nextSocket.emit("sendword", payload); // send to the neighbor
      swCallback({success:true})
    }
    else {
      swCallback({success:false})
    }
  })
});

/// Clients.js

io.emit("joingame", (jgCallbackResponse) => {
  if (jgCallbackResponse.success){
    // you are in the game
  }
})// Join the game.

io.on("sendword", (payload) => {
  // from the previous user in the chain
  console.log(payload.word)
})

io.emit("sendword", { word: "my word" }, (swCallbackResponse) => {
  if (swCallbackResponse.success){
    // word sent
  }
});
```